# pause and resume a thread javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to pause resume a javafx thread, here is service which manage start and pause of thread:

```
    package fxmlexample;

    import java.awt.MouseInfo;
    import javafx.concurrent.Task;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;`

public class myThreadService extends ScheduledService<Void>{

    private static int THREAD_LENGTH = 100;
    private boolean runFlag;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        setRunFlag(true);
        this.start();
    }

     @Override protected void succeeded() {
             super.succeeded();
         }


@Override protected void cancelled() {
             setRunFlag(false);
             super.cancelled();
         }


 @Override protected void failed() {
             super.failed();
         }
    public void resume() throws InterruptedException{
        try{
            this.resume();
            setRunFlag(true);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("error while resuming thread: "+e);
        }
    } 

    public void setRunFlag(boolean flag){
            this.runFlag = flag;
        }

        public boolean getRunFlag(){
            return runFlag;
        }

        @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_LENGTH; i++) {
                    if(!getRunFlag()){
                        this.cancel();
                        break;
                    }
                    int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                    int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
                    System.out.println("("+mouseX+","+mouseY+")"+getRunFlag());
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }        
}
```

I read some post which advise to use variable to decide wether thread should stop or continue. My problem is that once thread is running my getRunFlag is always returning true even if pause() is trigered. So thread continue to run.
Is there a way to get a specific running thread and then safely kill it ?

Comment: look into asynchronous threading.

Comment: There is no `pause` method in your code and the a task will be done in little more than 100 ms anyways and during the last 100 ms it won't let you cancel it...

Comment: Indeed there is no such method in my code. I meant `cancelled` method which set my `runFlag` to false and should force loop to exit.